# How to fix 'org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException' in quarkus native image

Tags: quarkus

I'm builting a maven multimodule project that integrates with amazon SSM, when i run on JVM Mode everything works fine. But when i generate the native image occurs an error

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl (Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl)
```

I have already tried this configuration

```
[
  {
    "name" : "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl",
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredFields" : true,
    "allPublicFields" : true
  }
]
```

my pom.xml native profile

```
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>native-image</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <enableHttpUrlHandler>true</enableHttpUrlHandler>
                                    <enableHttpsUrlHandler>true</enableHttpsUrlHandler>
                                    <additionalBuildArgs>
                                        <additionalBuildArg>
                                            -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=${project.basedir}/reflection-config.json
                                        </additionalBuildArg>
                                    </additionalBuildArgs>
                                </configuration>
```

Error that i got

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: No suitable Log implementation
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:848)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:292)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.<init>(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:58)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.getPreferredSocketFactory(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:63)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:50)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:38)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:324)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:308)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:229)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:215)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.<init>(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:614)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.<init>(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:600)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.build(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.java:61)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.build(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.java:27)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.defaultClient(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.java:45)
    at br.com.dummyproject.helpers.impl.InterSecureParamaterStoreLoaderImpl.loadParameters(InterSecureParamaterStoreLoaderImpl.java:26)
    at br.com.dummyproject.ApplicationStarted.onStart(ApplicationStarted.java:22)
    at br.com.dummyproject.ApplicationStarted_Observer_onStart_fd71b5e0b207b7d1ef838b94eaeff75e52b8f463.notify(ApplicationStarted_Observer_onStart_fd71b5e0b207b7d1ef838b94eaeff75e52b8f463.zig:61)
    at io.quarkus.arc.EventImpl$Notifier.notify(EventImpl.java:228)
    at io.quarkus.arc.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:69)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.LifecycleEventRunner.fireStartupEvent(LifecycleEventRunner.java:23)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.handleLifecycleEvents(ArcRecorder.java:99)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent16.deploy_0(LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent16.zig:58)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent16.deploy(LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent16.zig:77)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl1.doStart(ApplicationImpl1.zig:149)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.run(Application.java:196)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(GeneratedMain.zig:34)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl1.doStart(ApplicationImpl1.zig:169)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.run(Application.java:196)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(GeneratedMain.zig:34)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: No suitable Log implementation
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:848)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:292)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.<init>(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:58)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.getPreferredSocketFactory(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:63)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:50)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:38)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:324)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:308)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:229)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:215)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.<init>(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:614)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.<init>(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:600)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.build(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.java:61)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.build(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.java:27)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.defaultClient(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.java:45)
    at br.com.dummyproject.helpers.impl.InterSecureParamaterStoreLoaderImpl.loadParameters(InterSecureParamaterStoreLoaderImpl.java:26)
    at br.com.dummyproject.ApplicationStarted.onStart(ApplicationStarted.java:22)
    at br.com.dummyproject.ApplicationStarted_Observer_onStart_fd71b5e0b207b7d1ef838b94eaeff75e52b8f463.notify(ApplicationStarted_Observer_onStart_fd71b5e0b207b7d1ef838b94eaeff75e52b8f463.zig:61)
    at io.quarkus.arc.EventImpl$Notifier.notify(EventImpl.java:228)
    at io.quarkus.arc.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:69)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.LifecycleEventRunner.fireStartupEvent(LifecycleEventRunner.java:23)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.handleLifecycleEvents(ArcRecorder.java:99)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent16.deploy_0(LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent16.zig:58)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent16.deploy(LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent16.zig:77)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl1.doStart(ApplicationImpl1.zig:149)
```

My file application.properties is like

```
quarkus.resteasy.path=/api/inter-dummy-quarkus-project-service/v1
quarkus.log.file.enable=true
service.context=inter-dummy-quarkus-project-service

quarkus.log.file.path=/quarkus-projects/inter-dummy-quarkus-project-service/logs/log-error.log
quarkus.log.file.level=ERROR
quarkus.log.file.format={"timestamp":"%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", "service":"${service.context}", "thread":"[%t]", "level":"%p", "meta":%s}%n

quarkus.ssl.native=true
```

Complete stacktrace

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl (Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.createFactory(LogFactory.java:1158)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2.run(LogFactory.java:960)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.newFactory(LogFactory.java:957)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:624)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:292)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.<init>(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:58)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.getPreferredSocketFactory(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:63)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:50)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:38)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:324)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:308)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:229)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:215)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.<init>(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:614)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.<init>(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:600)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.build(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.java:61)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.build(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.java:27)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.defaultClient(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.java:45)
    at br.com.dummyproject.helpers.impl.InterSecureParamaterStoreLoaderImpl.loadParameters(InterSecureParamaterStoreLoaderImpl.java:26)
    at br.com.dummyproject.ApplicationStarted.onStart(ApplicationStarted.java:22)
    at br.com.dummyproject.ApplicationStarted_Observer_onStart_fd71b5e0b207b7d1ef838b94eaeff75e52b8f463.notify(ApplicationStarted_Observer_onStart_fd71b5e0b207b7d1ef838b94eaeff75e52b8f463.zig:61)
    at io.quarkus.arc.EventImpl$Notifier.notify(EventImpl.java:228)
    at io.quarkus.arc.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:69)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.LifecycleEventRunner.fireStartupEvent(LifecycleEventRunner.java:23)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.handleLifecycleEvents(ArcRecorder.java:99)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent16.deploy_0(LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent16.zig:58)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent16.deploy(LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent16.zig:77)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl1.doStart(ApplicationImpl1.zig:149)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.run(Application.java:196)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(GeneratedMain.zig:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl
    at com.oracle.svm.core.hub.ClassForNameSupport.forName(ClassForNameSupport.java:60)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Target_java_lang_ClassLoader.java:131)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.createFactory(LogFactory.java:1020)
    ... 36 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl1.doStart(ApplicationImpl1.zig:169)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.run(Application.java:196)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(GeneratedMain.zig:34)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl (Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.createFactory(LogFactory.java:1158)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2.run(LogFactory.java:960)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.newFactory(LogFactory.java:957)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:624)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:292)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.<init>(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:58)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.getPreferredSocketFactory(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:90)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:63)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:50)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:38)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:324)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:308)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:229)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:215)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.<init>(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:614)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.<init>(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:600)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.build(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.java:61)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.build(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.java:27)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.defaultClient(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.java:45)
    at br.com.dummyproject.helpers.impl.InterSecureParamaterStoreLoaderImpl.loadParameters(InterSecureParamaterStoreLoaderImpl.java:26)
    at br.com.dummyproject.ApplicationStarted.onStart(ApplicationStarted.java:22)
    at br.com.dummyproject.ApplicationStarted_Observer_onStart_fd71b5e0b207b7d1ef838b94eaeff75e52b8f463.notify(ApplicationStarted_Observer_onStart_fd71b5e0b207b7d1ef838b94eaeff75e52b8f463.zig:61)
    at io.quarkus.arc.EventImpl$Notifier.notify(EventImpl.java:228)
    at io.quarkus.arc.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:69)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.LifecycleEventRunner.fireStartupEvent(LifecycleEventRunner.java:23)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.handleLifecycleEvents(ArcRecorder.java:99)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent16.deploy_0(LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent16.zig:58)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent16.deploy(LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent16.zig:77)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl1.doStart(ApplicationImpl1.zig:149)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl
    at com.oracle.svm.core.hub.ClassForNameSupport.forName(ClassForNameSupport.java:60)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Target_java_lang_ClassLoader.java:131)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.createFactory(LogFactory.java:1020)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem Solved!

I did this configuration

In my pom.xml i put this configuration on native profile

```xml
<additionalBuildArgs>
    <additionalBuildArg>
        -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=${project.basedir}/reflection-config.json
    </additionalBuildArg>
    <additionalBuildArg>
        -H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles=${project.basedir}/proxy-config.json
    </additionalBuildArg>
    <additionalBuildArg>
        -H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=${project.basedir}/resource-config.json
    </additionalBuildArg>
</additionalBuildArgs>
```

reflection-config.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.amazonaws.partitions.model.Partitions",
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.amazonaws.partitions.model.Partition",
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.amazonaws.partitions.model.Endpoint",
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.amazonaws.partitions.model.Region",
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.amazonaws.partitions.model.Service",
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.amazonaws.partitions.model.CredentialScope",
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "java.util.HashSet",
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  },
  {
    "name": "java.lang.String",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  },
  {
    "name": "org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  },
  {
    "name": "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  }
]
```

proxy-config.json

```
[
  [
    "org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager",
    "org.apache.http.pool.ConnPoolControl",
    "com.amazonaws.http.conn.Wrapped"
  ]
]
```

resource-config.json

```
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "pattern": "com/amazonaws/partitions/endpoints.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Just to give my 2 cents.... We can move that pom.xml configuration to the application.properties, in this way `quarkus.native.additional-build-args =-H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=resources-config.json,-H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles=proxy-config.json,-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflection-config.json`